# How Can I Get Bootstrapped BCa Confidence Intervals for Spearman's Correlation Matrix in R?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, confidence-interval, bootstrapping

Good evening R experts,

I am generating a Spearman's correlation matrix in R using all variables under study for my current project. To be consistent with the other analyses I am conducting, I would like to construct BCa bootstrapped confidence intervals using 10,000 iterations around each Spearman's coefficient. However, I have not found an efficient and reliable method by which to achieve this end.

**I have created my Spearman's correlation matrix with coefficients and p-values using the following code. Note that I have generated random data for the sake of this example.**

```
library(psych)
library(rstatix)

df_test <- data.frame(
    recall=c(45, 1, 32, 17, 79, 15, 75, 100, 43, 80, 74, 91, 60, 54, 67, 26, 97, 53, 51, 30),
    recog=c(90, 29, 93, 73, 34, 68, 78, 56, 92, 85, 35, 81, 7, 58, 4, 52, 82, 31, 6, 23),
    hits=c(77, 89, 44, 8, 70, 96, 76, 62, 95, 27, 49, 12, 16, 28, 83, 2, 36, 10, 61, 86),
    misses=c(59, 78, 14, 44, 86, 61, 80, 72, 25, 93, 5, 42, 64, 95, 73, 54, 7, 67, 11, 53),
    false_alarms=c(32, 34, 55, 41, 77, 76, 89, 36, 12, 100, 70, 62, 47, 81, 90, 63, 13, 83, 79, 38)
)

df_test.cor <- cor(df_test, y = NULL, use = "pairwise.complete.obs",
    method = c("spearman"))

#Get coefficients
df_test.mat <- cor_mat(
  df_test,
  vars = NULL,
  method = "spearman",
  alternative = "two.sided",
  conf.level = 0.95
)

df_test.mat

#Get sig values
df_test.pmat <- cor_pmat(
  df_test,
  vars = NULL,
  method = "spearman",
  alternative = "two.sided",
  conf.level = 0.95
)

df_test.pmat

ggcorrplot(df_test.mat,
           type = "lower", method = "circle", colors = c("turquoise3", "khaki1", "violetred3"), p.mat = df_test.pmat)


cor.ci(df_test, keys = NULL, n.iter = 10000,  p = 0.050, poly = FALSE, method = "spearman")
```

The results are as follows:

**1. Correlation coefficients with p-values:**
[image]

**2. Visualization**

[image]

**3. Bootstrapped 95% CI's Using `psych` Package**
[image]

**There are a number of issues with these confidence intervals, enumerated below:**

1. First, the p-values from the CI calculation do not correspond to those generated using the `cor_pmat()` command from the `rstatix` package.
2. The CI approach used here does not allow me to select BCa as the bootstrapping method.
3. The p-values and CI boundaries are only reported up to 2 decimal places using the aforementioned approach. I require greater precision for my project, ideally with p-values and CI boundaries calculated up to 3 or 4 decimals.

Hence, my question is: **How might I construct bootstrapped confidence intervals around Spearman's coefficients in my entire correlation matrix using the BCa approach with precision up to 4 decimal places?**

Comment: 1) Yes, they do, bootstrapped statistics have built-in randomness, you can not expect exact equality; 3) assign `ps <- psych::cor.ci(...)` and then `print(ps, digits = 5)` to have p-values and CI boundaries with 5 decimals.

Comment: There is also the whole issue that your *P*-value is generated under the null distribution, whereas a bootstrap resamples your *sampling* distribution... You cannot expect these statistics to match because they answer different questions. You could consider back-transforming either CI or *P*-value into the other but that comes with quite strong assumptions. I'm also not too convinced that an acceleration factor is relevant for the non-parametric Spearman correlation.

Comment: This is a useful post for more about the p-value issue: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20701/83560

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at a very similar solution to Mikko Marttila's, though I still think there's no need to fixate so much on the BCa interval. I ran a simulation on the standard bivariate normal with correlation 0.5, for which the Spearman rank correlation is also known, and determined coverage properties of the most common bootstrap confidence intervals:

```r
## Using bivariate normal sampling distribution
rho <- .5
sigma <- matrix(rho, ncol=2, nrow=2)
diag(sigma) <- 1

## True Spearman rank correlation + coverage function
GROUND_TRUTH <- (6/pi)*asin(rho/2)
covers <- function(ci) (ci[1] <= GROUND_TRUTH) & (GROUND_TRUTH <= ci[2])

## Function to bootstrap a single Spearman correlation
bootfun <- function(data, i) {
   r <- cor(data[i,], method = "spearman")
   r[lower.tri(r)]
}

## Generate one sample & bootstrap it
## Returns whether the obtained intervals cover the true parameter
one_boot <- function(seed, n=100) {
   set.seed(seed)
   data <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n, sigma = sigma)
   b <- boot::boot(data, bootfun, R=1E4)
   ci <- boot::boot.ci(b, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca"))
   c("norm" = covers(ci$normal[2:3]),  "basic"= covers(ci$basic[4:5]),
     "perc" = covers(ci$percent[4:5]), "bca"  = covers(ci$bca[4:5]))
}

## Generate many samples & bootstrap each of them
## Returns coverage properties of each interval
future::plan("multisession", workers=4)
many_boots <- future.apply::future_vapply(seq_len(1E4), one_boot,
                                          logical(4), future.seed = TRUE) |>
   matrixStats::rowMeans2()
#>   norm  basic   perc    bca 
#> 0.9399 0.9297 0.9535 0.9544
```

As you can see, the raw percentiles have at least as good coverage properties as the BCa interval, and this is under the theoretically perfect standard normal (where the acceleration factor is also exact). If your sampling distribution has less well-defined skewness or isn't smooth this interval will perform *worse* than other alternatives.

As a bonus, here's how you can obtain a single two-sided *P*-value for Spearman correlation through resampling (under the null!):

```r
permute_spearman <- function(x, y, iters=1E4) {
   t0 <- cor(x, y, method="spearman")
   mean(vapply(seq_len(iters), \(d) {
      abs(cor(x, y[sample(seq_along(y))], method="spearman")) > abs(t0)
   }, logical(1)))
}
```

Comment: That's very useful exploration! For the permutation test, should you also have `abs(t0)` as currently you'd always just get 1 if `t0` is negative?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila you're right, I corrected this. You don't want to take the absolute values if you want a one-sided test.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate BCa intervals with the [boot](https://cran.r-project.org/package=boot) package.

First, create a statistic function for the Spearman correlations for a subset `i` of the data:

```r
spearman <- function(d, i) {
  rho <- cor(d[i, ], method = "spearman")
  rho[lower.tri(rho)]
}
```

Then, get bootstrap samples with `boot()`:

```r
set.seed(42)
boot_out <- boot::boot(df_test, spearman, R = 10000)
boot_out
#> 
#> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#> 
#> 
#> Call:
#> boot::boot(data = df_test, statistic = spearman, R = 10000)
#> 
#> 
#> Bootstrap Statistics :
#>         original       bias    std. error
#> t1*   0.09172932 -0.004161858   0.2181451
#> t2*  -0.22105263  0.008094763   0.2623494
#> t3*   0.13684211 -0.009041776   0.2462778
#> t4*   0.22406015 -0.004986228   0.2420079
#> t5*  -0.05413534  0.003039217   0.2235030
#> t6*  -0.18345865  0.006896525   0.2341026
#> t7*  -0.29022556  0.006665581   0.2469688
#> t8*   0.08872180 -0.004816326   0.1924127
#> t9*  -0.20902256  0.011034138   0.2315252
#> t10*  0.48120301 -0.021141040   0.2029307
```

Finally, calculate confidence intervals with `boot.ci()`. `index` specifies
which element of the output statistic you want the intervals for:

```r
boot::boot.ci(boot_out, type = "bca", index = 10)
#> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
#> Based on 10000 bootstrap replicates
#> 
#> CALL : 
#> boot::boot.ci(boot.out = boot_out, type = "bca", index = 10)
#> 
#> Intervals : 
#> Level       BCa          
#> 95%   (-0.0322,  0.7649 )  
#> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

A vector `index` has a different meaning (the 2nd element is interpreted as giving the variance of the 1st), so to get all CIs
you’ll need to explicitly iterate, for example with `lapply()`:

```r
lapply(seq_along(boot_out$t0), function(i) {
  boot::boot.ci(boot_out, type = "bca", index = i)
})
```

If you want only the intervals from the output, you can extract them from the `$bca` element:

```r
sapply(seq_along(boot_out$t0), function(i) {
  boot::boot.ci(boot_out, type = "bca", index = i)$bca[, 4:5]
})
#>        [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]
#>  -0.3439443 -0.6648910 -0.3743482 -0.3385006 -0.4651028 -0.6057627 -0.7137479
#>   0.5040802  0.3668189  0.5936317  0.6228635  0.4083453  0.3079268  0.2545514
#>        [,8]       [,9]      [,10]
#>  -0.2991324 -0.6217852 -0.0321938
#>   0.4506211  0.2709281  0.7648544
```

Comment: Hi @Mikko Marttila , this is tremendously helpful to me, and I sincerely appreciate your thoughtful answer. I hope you will forgive my ignorance, but how might I show use this to iterate each CI for each bivariate correlation? I tried altering the index input, but even in doing so it defaults to index = 1: 

b <- 1:10
boot::boot.ci(boot_out, type = "bca", index = b)

How can I make it so that the CIs for all correlations are printed at once?

Comment: @LindaJasmineHoffman that's a good attempt, and usually how things would work in R. Unfortunately in `boot.ci()` a vector `index` has a different meaning. I've edited my answer accordingly.